# How to fix this eth0 and eth1, where traffic going out via eth0 is failing?

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn, openvpn, ipsec

I have two public IPs. One's connected to eth0 and one to eth1, from 2 separate routers as complete DMZ towards the LAN IP.

I added this following:

```
ip rule add from 10.0.0.108/32 table 1 # outbound
ip rule add to 10.0.0.108/32 table 1   # inbound
ip route add default via 10.0.0.1 dev eth0 table 1
ip rule add from 10.0.0.100/32 table 2 # outbound
ip rule add to 10.0.0.100/32 table 2   # inbound
ip route add default via 10.0.0.1 dev eth1 table 2
```

Since adding this above, I've been having problems sending traffic correctly for inbound and outbound.

For example:

```
$ ping -I eth0 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) from 10.0.0.108 eth0: 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.0.0.108 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.0.108 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.0.108 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable

$ ping -I eth1 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) from 10.0.0.28 eth1: 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=48 time=14.6 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=48 time=14.6 ms
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1233ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 14.611/14.639/14.667/0.028 ms
```

How do I use `ip rule add from/to` method to fix the eth0 (from/to), but without  breaking the eth1 (eth1 is working perfect).

Answer (score 0):

it seems you're routing all traffic through eth1 (`default via 10.0.0.1 dev eth1 table 2` is prefered over `default via 10.0.0.1 dev eth0 table 1`) but using `-I eth0` just replaces `src IP` of `icmp` packets (correct me if I'm not right).
Also, does `10.0.0.1` gateway exist in both networks?

I believe [this LARTC article](http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html) should definitely help you. 
Btw, it would be nice if you provide us with more network configuration detail.